# Having issues with Advanced Rest Client and testing POST GET checker

Tags: rest, post

I am using the Advanced Rest Client (ARC) to test my POST functions in my GET/POST checker that I am building for a class assignment.  The ARC keeps displaying this:

```
Status
0 NO RESPONSE Show explanation Loading time: 2012
Request headers 
foo: bar
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Any idea's?  I have tested the instructors code and my code...same result.  I will share any code anyone needs to see; I apologize, you are guiding the blind right now as I have no idea what to show you.

Comment: @peeskillet I am trying to use ARC to send a POST request to my server.  It should not be saying 'no response'.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think anyone will be able to help you solve this problem without more information. The cause could be an infinite number of reasons, without more to go off of.

Comment: I don't know what to share with you; I apologize if I have wasted anyone's time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nothing in my code was wrong on the server.  A couple of notes:
ARC does not like http://localhost (This should have been obvious to me)
ARC does not like just an ip address with a port number either.  This is less obvious to me and maybe someone can answer this?

Recap:
ARC needs http://[IP address]:port#